# Colocar uma tag HTML em cima do </body> utilizando string (PHP)

Tags: php, html

Olá estou fazendo um software de enviar E-mails em PHP. A pessoa tem um formulário e ela envia HTML por um link. Porém aqui irei colocar um HTML simples.

```
$texto = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang='pt-br'>
<head>
 <meta charset='UTF-8'>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='estilo.css'>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<!--conteúdo do BODY -->
<!--Tag a ser inserida -->
</body>
</html>";
```

O que eu quero é inserir uma tag no final da tag **body** antes do **/body**.

```
<table class="dashedBorder" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="width: 550">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="middle" align="center" style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; WHITE-SPACE: normal; FONT-SIZE: 11px">
<font color="#444444">Esse email foi enviado para fulano@email.com.br para parar de receber e-mails clique <a href="">aqui</a> </font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr> </tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Como eu posso fazer isto em PHP? Levando em conta que todo arquivo do **$texto** vai ter um **/body** dentro da variável?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize a função `str_replace` que serve para substituir uma parte do texto por outra em uma string. Por exemplo, no seu caso:

```
$textoAdicional = '<table>...</table>';
$texto = str_replace('</body>', $textoAdicional . '</body>', $texto);
```

Desta forma, estou substituindo na variável `$texto` a string `</body>` por `<table>...</table></body>`.

Answer (score 2):

Use o [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) para imprimir o texto:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($texto);
```

Essa função irá escapar todos os caracteres especiais do HTML.

---

Um detalhe, seu código PHP está inválido, pois você está  abrindo a string utilizando aspas duplas e no meio do texto está fechando-a, utilizando as aspas duplas, mesmo essa não sendo sua intenção. O correto seria você utilizar aspas simples no interior do HTML. Exemplo:

```
$texto = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang='pt-br'>
<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='estilo.css'>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<!--conteúdo do BODY -->
<!--Tag a ser inserida -->
</body>
</html>";
```

Para você não ter que se preocupar com as aspas, use [Heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) na criação de suas strings, veja como fica melhor e elegante:

```
$texto = <<<EOD
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<!--conteúdo do BODY -->
<!--Tag a ser inserida -->
</body>
</html>
EOD;
```

Comment: Por que você mostrou como exibir o texto?

Comment: Mas esta função dá suporte para substituir a string do HTML, além de imprimi-lo?

Comment: Falhei em compreender a pergunta, a solução do @Oeslei é o que precisa. Pensei que queria imprimir o HTML em texto.

Comment: Tudo bem, sua resposta é bem útil apesar disto. =)